# Analysis of multiple response

Tags: r, spss, survey

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(c("male", "female", "male"),
             c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
             seq(141, 170))

names(df1) = c("gender", "age", "height")

df1$age <- factor(
  df1$age,
  levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  labels = c("16-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65+")
)

q1a = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
q1b = c(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0)
q1c = c(0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3)
# 1,2 and 3 used to be compatible with existing datasets. 
# Could change all to 1 if necessary.

df2 <- data.frame(q1a = q1a, q1b = q1b, q1c = q1c)
df1 <- cbind(df1, df2)

rm(q1a, q1b, q1c, df2)
```

I am looking to replicate the analysis of multiple response questions from SPSS in R.

At the moment I am using this code:

```
#creating function for analysing questions with grouped data
multfreqtable <- function(a, b, c) {
  # number of respondents (for percent of cases)
  totrep = sum(a == 1 | b == 2 | c == 3)
  
  #creating frequency table
  table_a = data.frame("a", sum(a == 1))
  names(table_a) = c("question", "freq")
  table_b = data.frame("b", sum(b == 2))
  names(table_b) = c("question", "freq")
  table_c = data.frame("c", sum(c == 3))
  names(table_c) = c("question", "freq")
  table_question <- rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
  
  #remove individual question tables
  rm(table_a, table_b, table_c)
  
  #adding total
  total = as.data.frame("Total")
  totalsum = (sum(table_question$freq, na.rm = TRUE))
  totalrow = cbind(total, totalsum)
  names(totalrow) = c("question", "freq")
  table_question = rbind(table_question, totalrow)
  
  #adding percentage column to frequency table
  percentcalc = as.numeric(table_question$freq)
  percent = (percentcalc / totalsum) * 100
  table_question <- cbind(table_question, percent)
  
  #adding percent of cases column to frequency table
  poccalc = as.numeric(table_question$freq)
  percentofcases = (poccalc / totrep) * 100
  table_question <- cbind(table_question, percentofcases)
  
  #print percent of cases value
  total_respondents <<- data.frame(totrep)
  
  #remove all unnecessary data and values
  rm(
    total,
    totalsum,
    totalrow,
    b,
    c,
    percent,
    percentcalc,
    percentofcases,
    totrep,
    poccalc
  )
  
  return(table_question)
}

#calling function - must tie to data.frame using $ !!!
q1_frequency <- multfreqtable(df1$q1a, df1$q1b, df1$q1c)

#renaming percent of cases - This is very important while using current method
total_respondents_q1 <- total_respondents
rm(total_respondents)
```

Producing this table as a result:

[image: Output table]

I am looking for a more efficient method of doing this that ideally would not require the function to be edited if there were more or less multiple choice questions.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your earlier question.  What has changed?  Please post your expected results, since I am not going to try and decipher your code again, but can most likely point you to an existing function once I know what you want.

Comment: @Andrie This is the same code as with my earlier post, it is only the focus of the question that has changed. The image above shows the output table from my code. Sorry if that is not the best way of demonstrating my expected results.

Comment: So you're trying to make this function more generic?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik. Yes, ideally I would like to specify a range of questions to analyse in this way. As mentioned if it is easier to use 1s for every question then that would be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your function is actually far too complicated for what you need to do. I think a function like this should work and be more flexible.

```
multfreqtable = function(data, question.prefix) {
  # Find the columns with the questions
  a = grep(question.prefix, names(data))
  # Find the total number of responses
  b = sum(data[, a] != 0)
  # Find the totals for each question
  d = colSums(data[, a] != 0)
  # Find the number of respondents
  e = sum(rowSums(data[,a]) !=0)
  # d + b as a vector. This is your overfall frequency 
  f = as.numeric(c(d, b))
  data.frame(question = c(names(d), "Total"),
             freq = f,
             percent = (f/b)*100,
             percentofcases = (f/e)*100 )
}
```

Add another question to your example dataset:

```
set.seed(1); df1$q2a = sample(c(0, 1), 30, replace=T)
set.seed(2); df1$q2b = sample(c(0, 2), 30, replace=T)
set.seed(3); df1$q2c = sample(c(0, 3), 30, replace=T)
```

Make a table for "q1" responses:

```
> multfreqtable(df1, "q1")
  question freq   percent percentofcases
1      q1a   15  33.33333             60
2      q1b   15  33.33333             60
3      q1c   15  33.33333             60
4    Total   45 100.00000            180
```

Make a table for "q2" responses:

```
> multfreqtable(df1, "q2")
  question freq   percent percentofcases
1      q2a   14  31.11111       53.84615
2      q2b   13  28.88889       50.00000
3      q2c   18  40.00000       69.23077
4    Total   45 100.00000      173.07692
```

### Tables for multiple questions

Here's a modified version of the function that allows you to create a list of tables for multiple questions at once:

```
multfreqtable = function(data, question.prefix) {
  z = length(question.prefix)
  temp = vector("list", z)

  for (i in 1:z) {
    a = grep(question.prefix[i], names(data))
    b = sum(data[, a] != 0)
    d = colSums(data[, a] != 0)
    e = sum(rowSums(data[,a]) !=0)
    f = as.numeric(c(d, b))
    temp[[i]] = data.frame(question = c(sub(question.prefix[i], 
                                            "", names(d)), "Total"),
                           freq = f,
                           percent = (f/b)*100,
                           percentofcases = (f/e)*100 )
    names(temp)[i] = question.prefix[i]
  }
  temp
}
```

Examples:

```
> multfreqtable(df1, "q1")
$q1
  question freq   percent percentofcases
1        a   15  33.33333             60
2        b   15  33.33333             60
3        c   15  33.33333             60
4    Total   45 100.00000            180

> test1 = multfreqtable(df1, c("q1", "q2"))
> test1
$q1
  question freq   percent percentofcases
1        a   15  33.33333             60
2        b   15  33.33333             60
3        c   15  33.33333             60
4    Total   45 100.00000            180

$q2
  question freq   percent percentofcases
1        a   14  31.11111       53.84615
2        b   13  28.88889       50.00000
3        c   18  40.00000       69.23077
4    Total   45 100.00000      173.07692

> test1$q1
  question freq   percent percentofcases
1        a   15  33.33333             60
2        b   15  33.33333             60
3        c   15  33.33333             60
4    Total   45 100.00000            180
```

Comment: Hello, this seems to do exactly what I want. Having the option of multiple outputs from the same command is also something that could come in very handy.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I've tried it with zero responses and all answers coded as 1 which were two of the main things I had issues with and haven't seen any problems so far.

Comment: I've been trying to use adapt this code for a weighted data set and am having no luck. In my original code I achieved this by using `xtabs` instead of `table`. `colSums` seems to count the cases in each column regardless of their value. Is it possible to apply a weighting here?

Comment: Thank you. Haven't yet had time to look at this again since, I will think about whether it is best to update or add a new question.

Comment: This is really cool--but it does not work if the cols are character/factor vars huh?

Comment: It also does work if there are missing values :(

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question. However, you can use `userfriendlyscience` package to analyze multiple responses survey data very easily.

```
library(userfriendlyscience)
multiResponse (data, c('v1', 'v2', 'v3'))
```

Comment: Actually that function in *userfriendlyscience* is inspired by the accepted answer. Check `?multiResponse`

Comment: There is also the expss R package.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this is post is quite old, however I couldn’t find a more up to date solution.  Here's my version based on dplyr/tidyverse approach.

```
mult_resp = function(df1, mv_q = c("q1a", "q1b", "q1c")){

  df2 = df1 %>%
    mutate(id = rownames(.)) %>%  #row id for counting n_cases
    select(id, everything()) %>% 
    mutate_at(mv_q, ~ ifelse(. != 0, 1, 0)) %>%
    gather(question, resp,-id, -gender,-age,-height) 

  #count number of cases excluding "all zeros" cases
  n_cases = df2 %>% group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(resp)) %>% 
    summarise(sum(n > 0))

  #output table
  res = df2 %>% 
    group_by(question) %>%
    summarise(freq = sum(resp)) %>%
    mutate(
      percent = freq/sum(freq) *100,
      percent_of_cases = freq/as.numeric(n_cases)*100
      ) %>% 
    rbind(., 
          data.frame(question ="Total", 
                     freq =sum(.$freq, na.rm=TRUE),
                     percent =sum(.$percent, na.rm=TRUE),
                     percent_of_cases = sum(.$percent_of_cases, na.rm=TRUE)
                     )
          )
    res
}
```

Example:

```
> mult_resp(df1, mv_q = c("q1a", "q1b", "q1c"))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  question  freq percent percent_of_cases
  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>
1 q1a         15    33.3               60
2 q1b         15    33.3               60
3 q1c         15    33.3               60
4 Total       45   100.               180
```